# Filemaker 13 calculations among unrelated tables

Tags: database, filemaker

I'm using this database where I have several tables which store the information about receipts and expenses.

What I would like to do is to produce a format where I put the overall balance, i.e. (Table1.Receipts_total + Table2.Receipts_total) - ( Table3.Expenses_total + Table4.Expenses_total)

The main problem here is that these tables are not related each-other and it seems very difficult to deal with this aspect in FileMaker.

I thought that there was a way to runa a low-level "raw" SQL statement, but I was not able to do that.

Comment: I am sure you can do this using `ExecuteSQL()` - but what exactly will you do with the result? Also, why don't you simply relate the tables? Or - even better - combine them into one Transactions table? -- Note also that summarizing **all* transactions all the time does not seem very practical (and will get slower as the number of records grows). Usually, you would perform a find (say for  transactions in a date range), then show this in a report.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Unfortunately the different tables do not have a "logical" relationship, but I need to get out some information from their records. It seems that the `ExecuteSQL` does not provide me the information I need (because it states that there are no relationships). I store information about expenses and receipts in different tables, and then I would like to aggregate all these info to get an overall balance

Comment: "*It seems that the ExecuteSQL does not provide me the information I need (because it states that there are no relationships).*" ExecuteSQL() does not require relationships. Please post your code to move this forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest you normalize your data structure - since whatever you do with the current one will be just a hack.

Anyway, it's quite easy to get the figure you want even without using `ExecuteSQL()` - just run a simple script like:

```
Go to Layout [ Table1.Receipts ] 
Show All Records 
Set Variable [ $balance; Value:Table1.Receipts::sTotalAmount ] 
Go to Layout [ Table2.Receipts ] 
Show All Records 
Set Variable [ $balance; Value:$balance + Table2.Receipts::sTotalAmount ] 
Go to Layout [ Table3.Expenses ] 
Show All Records 
Set Variable [ $balance; Value:$balance - Table3.Expenses::sTotalAmount ]
```

At this point, the `$balance` variable will contain the requested number, and you can do whatever you want to do with it.

**Note**: the `sTotalAmount` fields are summary fields defined as `Total of [Amount]` in each of the three tables.

---

Alternatively, you could relate the three tables using the `x` relational operator (i.e. create a Cartesian product relationship), then use a calculation, say in the `Table1.Receipts` table, =

```
sTotalAmount + Table2.Receipts::sTotalAmount - Table3.Expenses::sTotalAmount
```

But I would not recommend you place this as a "live" calculation field on the layout, as this will get increasingly slower as the number of transaction grows.